# XML Key/Value manipulation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have data like this -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <key>{Salary}</key>
    <value>1000</value>
</item>
```

I want my output to look like this -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <Salary>1000</Salary>
</item>
```

Edit, instead of just a value, if I had other tags only one of which is guaranteed to be nonempty like so, what is wrong with my transform? I'm using Sean's XSLT 1.0 transform as a source.

Input -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <key>{Salary}</key>
    <value />
    <value2>1000</value2>
    <value3 />
</item>
```

Desired output -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <Salary>1000</Salary>
</item>
```

My current transform -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key">
<xsl:element name="{substring-before(substring-after(.,'{'),'}')}"> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="value != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="value2 != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value2" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="value3 != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value3" />
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 1.0 solution ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>      

<xsl:template match="value" />

<xsl:template match="key">
 <xsl:element name="{substring-before(substring-after(.,'{'),'}')}"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value" /> 
 </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### update

Here also is an XSLT 2 solution. This is untested.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="element()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute()|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value" />

<xsl:template match="key">
 <xsl:element name="{fn:replace(.,'^\{(.*)\}$','$1')}"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value" /> 
 </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to state that there's no guarantee that value comes right after key....It might look like this `<item><name>Bob</name><key>{Salary}</key><fav_food>pizza</fav_food><value>1000</value></item>`

Comment: @Narabhut it will still work in that case.  The `value-of` in the `key` template will take the first following-sibling `value` element even if there are other siblings with different names in between the `key` and the `value`.  If it might be the case that the `key` comes after the `value` then use `../value` instead of `following-sibling::value`.

Comment: I've updated the question with another problem I'm having. Thanks!

Comment: @Narabhut it would be better if you could make your second problem into a separate question. On SO each question can only have one accepted answer so it's clearer if you don't mix a new problem into an existing question that already has a correct answer.

Comment: @Narabhut, I look forward to your follow-up question. Be sure and specify which version of XSLT you are using (1.0, 2.0 or proto-3.0).

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Here is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278477/xml-key-value-manipulation-on-condition-using-xslt) I am using XSLT 2.0