# XML Key/value manipulation on condition using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have data like this -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <key>Salary</key>
    <value />
    <value2>1000</value2>
    <value3 />
</item>
```

I want my output to look like this -

```
<item>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <fav_food>pizza</fav_food>
    <Salary>1000</Salary>
</item>
```

In this case, Salary gets the value of 1000 because value is empty and value2 is not (value has higher priority than value2, which has higher priority than value3).

It is guaranteed that value,value2 and value3 all exist, and only one of those is nonempty. Is it possible to use a XSLT transform to do this?

Currently, this is my transform.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(substring-after(.,'{'),'}')}"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="value != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="value2 != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value2" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="value3 != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::value3" />
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could there be multiple `<key>`s per `<item>`? That would be important to know. I'm guessing no, based on your code. Also, does your code work correctly, and you just want a better way to do it? Or is there a problem with your code? If so, please show actual output.

Comment: I'm guaranteed only one key per item. My code doesn't work, basically I'm getting an empty string for all my keys regardless of what my values are.

Comment: Empty strings where? Please show the output you're getting. Also, why do you have the `substring-after()` etc. when there are no `{` in your input? Or if the input you showed isn't realistic in that way, please show realistic input.

Comment: The substring-after() was because my key was formatted like `<key>{Salary}</key>`and I had to take out the {}. The solution posted by Mark however works (when I add the substring-after()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="key">
  <xsl:element name="{.}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../(value, value2, value3)/text()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/value | item/value2 | item/value3"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might want or need to adjust the element name generation but I have not applied your `name="{substring-before(substring-after(.,'{'),'}')}"` as I don't see any braces in your input sample.

Comment: I was going to suggest `xsl:value-of select="../(value, value2, value3)" separator=""` but it's the same idea. But given the talk of "priorities", I strongly suspect we haven't seen a complete spec.